# Client URL is being used as prefix whereas I have requested server URL POST

Tags: node.js, reactjs

the below attached file is my Login.js (client side)

```
const createOrUpdateUser = async (authtoken) => {
  return await axios.post(
    `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/create-or-update-user`,
    {},
    {
      headers: {
        authtoken:authtoken, 
      },
    }
  );
};
```

Here is my env file

```
REACT_APP_REGISTER_REDIRECT_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/register/complete'
REACT_APP_FORGOT_PASSWORD_REDIRECT ='http://localhost:3000/login'
REACT_APP_API = 'http://localhost:8000/api'
```

The Output :
As shown in the image below, I have a POST request for http://localhost:800/api and then in the login file I have post-fixed it with /create-or-update-user but it throws a Status Code : 404 Error

The Output just in case the image doesn't load :
*Request URL: http://localhost:3000/'http://localhost:8000/api'/create-or-update-user*
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxije.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have superfluous quotes there, remove all the `'` from your environment variables:

```
REACT_APP_REGISTER_REDIRECT_URL=http://localhost:3000/register/complete
REACT_APP_FORGOT_PASSWORD_REDIRECT=http://localhost:3000/login
REACT_APP_API=http://localhost:8000/api
```

Since `'http://localhost:8000/api'/create-or-update-user` isn't a valid absolute URL (it starts with a quote and not a protocol), it's interpreted as relative URL right now.

Comment: I am still a learner as a react developer and was using those quotes as shown in one of the tutorials but now edited without those quotes and it works!